# Who is the first person to quote verses from Uttara Khanda of Padma Purana targeting Shankara and his philosophy?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, padma-purana

Uttara khanda, chapter 236 of Padma Purana classifies Puranas into three categories and attacks Shankara's Advaita by saying Shiva incarnated as Shankara to preach a doctrine that resembles Vedas but actually it is apparent. [Many philosophers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17249/why-is-sankaracharya-accused-as-pracchana-bauddha-crypto-buddhist-by-many-veda) who preached other Vedanta philosophies accused Shankara and his philosophy as crypto-Buddhist and Crypto-Buddhism respectively. My question here is, who is the first ever person quoted verses from Padma Purana 6.236 while accusing him?

Answer (score 3):

The earliest reference I can find, comes from Krishna Dasa Kaviraja Goswami's Chaitanya Charitamrita in the sixteenth century:

> ***māyāvādam asac-chāstraṁ pracchannaṁ bauddham ucyate
>   mayaiva vihitaṁ devi
>   kalau brāhmaṇa-mūrtinā***
>
> **English Translation**: "[Lord Śiva informed goddess Durgā, the superintendent of the material world:] **‘In the Age of Kali I take the form of a brāhmaṇa and explain the Vedas through false scriptures in an atheistic way, similar to Buddhist philosophy.’** ” (**Śrī Caitanya-caritāmṛta, Madhya-līlā, Verse 182**)

The above verse is a quotation from the Padma Purana, Uttara-Khanda, Chapter 236.